# Update a field in table A with the max value of field in table B

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I want to update a field, let's call it 'field_A', in table 'table_A' with the maximum value that exists of field 'field_B' in 'table_B', but only IF there is a max value for that field 'field_B' in table 'table_B'.

Table 'table_B' has a 'reference' field which contains the 'id' of the table_A record we want to update.

Now I have the following query, which works perfectly.

```
UPDATE table_A a SET a.field_A = (SELECT MAX(b.field_B) 
    FROM table_B WHERE b.reference = a.id) 
WHERE a.id IN (
    SELECT reference
    FROM table_B
    GROUP BY reference
    HAVING COUNT(reference) > 0
)
```

So it only updates field_A IF there are records found for that reference because I don't want to end up setting fields 'field_A' to zero when no related records were found.

As I said before, this query already works perfectly, but now I have to run a query for table_B two times, which seems a little bit inefficient and it is probably possible to do it with only 1 join statement but I can't seem to tackle the issue.

Since this query has to cross reference a lot, really a lot, of records, performance is really an issue here.

Comment: I tried to formulate the question as generic as possible, I hope it's clear :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these two nested statements, your UPDATE statements seems quite 
inefficient to me. Try this SQL statement below, that should do the job.

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5825a/2

```
UPDATE table_A a1

JOIN 

(

    SELECT a.id as id, max(b.field_B) as max_val
    FROM
    table_A a
    LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.id = b.reference 
    GROUP BY a.id

) t on a1.id = t.id

SET

a1.field_A = t.max_val

WHERE

(t.max_val IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Is JOIN not going to increase query execution time and there by affecting performance?

Comment: @Akanksha No, this is better than OP's attempt. You need at least one JOIN anyway.

Comment: @Akanksha I am not either :)

Comment: @peter.petrov Thanks Peter, this does exactly what I meant and, as I expected, it DOES make a difference perfomance-wise.